# how to get last two bytes from a hex string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have output = ( b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x03\x04\x04\x00\x00\x07\xd0').
I would like to get last two bytes (07d0).
After that, I have to convert them to decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int.from_bytes` can convert any number of bytes to an integer, but you must know if you want the conversion little-endian or big-endian:

```
>>> output = b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x03\x04\x04\x00\x00\x07\xd0'
>>> output[-2:]  # start 2 bytes from the end and grab until end
b'\x07\xd0'
>>> int.from_bytes(output[-2:],'little')
53255
>>> int.from_bytes(output[-2:],'big')
2000
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(output[-2:],'little'))
'0xd007'
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(output[-2:],'big'))
'0x7d0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me:

```
bytes_test =  b'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x07\x03\x04\x04\x00\x00\x07\xd0'
print(int.from_bytes(bytes_test[-2:],"big"))
```